# Are Hume's ideas, actually complex ideas?

Tags: hume

Hume stated that there are simple and complex ideas.
For example, the idea of a pegasus, is complex, because it's composed by "simple" ideas (a horse and wings).

But is this very idea about simple and complex ideas, **complex**?

I mean, are Hume's ideas just bigger complex ideas, made of other simple ideas like the fantasy creature pegasus?

If so, does this proove Hume's theories as erroneous?

Comment: Why would this "prove Hume's theories as erroneous"?

Comment: It isn't any obvious sort of contradiction if the idea "there are simple ideas" is itself not a simple idea.